# C++ WndProc get message X and Y coordinates

Tags: c++, visual-c++, coordinates, win32gui

I'm not new to C++, however the concept of Win32 programming is fairly new to me.  Anyway, I was having some trouble getting the X and Y coordinates when a WM_NCHITTEST message is passed through WndProc.  To attempt to get them right now, I'm using the following code:

```
int x = LOWORD(lParam);
int y = HIWORD(lParam);
```

I'm not quite sure if it's working or not, but I believe it is.  I read somewhere that this actually returns the x and y coordinates of the pointer on the monitor itself, not relative to the application.

When I did extensive google searching when trying to figure out how to convert it into the coordinates relative to the application, I came across this method (or function.  I'm not in java anymore :P):

```
Point relativePos = theControl.PointToClient(pos);
```

where pos is the the x and y coordinates. I'd absolutely love to try this code out, however I'm running into multiple issues.

First of all, dots don't work in C++.  I've tried them, and they don't work.  Second of all, in Win32, I don't believe Point is defined.  I can find POINT, however I'm not sure that's the same thing.  Lastly, I'm honestly not quite sure how to define the point.

To explain why I need this, I'm trying to make the window draggable by only the top 50 pixels of the window.

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
    hit = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    if(y < 50)
        return HTCAPTION;
    break;
```

Anyway, your help is *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [documentation for WM_NCHITTEST on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), use `GET_X_LPARAM` and `GET_Y_LPARAM` from windowsx.h instead of `LOWORD` and `HIWORD` to get coordinate values from an `LPARAM`. You can convert the coordinates to client coordinates if you really want to by storing them in a `POINT` and then calling `ScreenToClient` like this:

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
```

However, I'm not sure there's a real benefit to doing that here. Notably, the client area begins *inside* the window frame, so (0, 0) in client coordinates is not the upper left corner of the window.

Probably what you really want is `GetWindowRect`, which gives you the bounding rectangle of the whole window in screen coordinates. You can figure out from there what the top 50 pixels are.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I learned quite a bit from this post.  And yes, I do want the client area as I'm creating my own bounding rectangle within it.  Thanks again!